# Woocommerce Email settings, Content type dropdown not working

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Not able to update the Woocommerce content type in email settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? Do you mean the settings don't save?

Answer (score 0):

This will sound odd, but if you remove the  emoji from the Additional Content area, your content-type changes should save. I have some more details on the problem [here](https://www.mail-mechanic.com/woocommerce-email-settings-not-saving) if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

When Installed the below package on the server hosting, it started working.

apt install php-gd php-xml php-xmlrpc